# Selenium Java - Getting the list of urls from google search and taking a count match of a specific url text

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am looking for a logic/code which will enter text *selenium* in google.com and from the search results it will fetch the first 10 urls list and from this list it will count which urls start with *www.seleniumhq.org*.

So far my code is able to display the first 10 urls list:

```
public static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String url = "https://google.com";
    driver.get(url);
    WebElement find = driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
    find.sendKeys("Selenium");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement click = driver.findElement(By.name("btnG"));
    click.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    List<WebElement> listings = driver.findElements(By.tagName("div").xpath("//cite[@class='_Rm']"));
    listings.size();
    System.out.println("Fetched URL's are as follows:-");

    for (WebElement loop : listings) {
        System.out.println(loop.getText());

        String filtering=loop.getText();
        boolean filtered=filtering.startsWith("www.seleniumhq.org/");

        int size1 = filtering.split("www.seleniumhq.org").length-1;

        System.out.println(size1);
    }
}
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying in that line where you are using `split` in this case. But if your motive is to just get the number of URLs starting with 'www.seleniumhq.org', I changed your `for` loop and I'm able to get the correct count:

```
    int size1 = 0;
    for (WebElement loop : listings) {

        System.out.println(loop.getText());

        String filtering=loop.getText();
        if(filtering.startsWith("www.seleniumhq.org"))
            size1++;
    }
    System.out.println("Total count : "+size1);
```

Comment: The split is used to separate out all the text "www.seleniumhq.org" from the fetched url's so in a way that too gives the correct count as the way you suggested but the output is in incremental form since it iterates through the for loop i.e first iteration it will be 0, then 1, etc. Is there any way i can get the count printed in one go ? like "The total url's statrting with www.seleniumhq.org are: 3" ?

Comment: You can put the print/use the size after the loop. Since we are maintaining a list here, in order to scan everything the loop is necessary. But once the loop completes, you will get the count and I guess that is all you need.